# Reclaiming expired keys in Redis

Tags: redis

I'm trying to solve the following problem in Redis.

I have a list that contains various available keys:

```
List MASTER:
111A
222B
333C
444D
555E
```

I'd like to be able to pop an element off of the list and use it as a key with an expires.

After the expires is up, I'd like to be able to push this number back onto MASTER for future use.  I don't see any obvious way to do this, so I'm soliciting for a creative one.

Comment: I would suggest against re-using keys when using the EXPIRE command in Redis like you described -- that's not the purpose.

Comment: Would you feel any different if it wasn't part of a key?  Say a value that needs to be reclaimed for future use?  I'm not sure it's an issue either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best method would be to get called back by Redis when the key expires and then take action. 
However, callbacks support is still to be added (http://code.google.com/p/redis/issues/detail?id=360). 
You can either use a Redis version that contains a custom/community modification to support this feature (like the last one in the link I've posted), or worse :): start tracking keys and timeouts in your client app.

Comment: Or don't he could not do it wrong and use GUID keys that can be generated and thrown away.